# how can i access C# dll from VBScript on client machine

Tags: c#, dll, vbscript

i have created a C# dll file on my machine as shown below:

```
namespace myDLL
{   
   public class myClass
   {
      public string myFunction()
      {
          return "I am Here";
       }
   } 
}
```

then i created a tlb file with "tlbexp" command,
then i used the "regasm" command n registered this dll on my machine.

When i created an object of type myClass on my machine using VBScript, everything is working fine... here i used the CreateObject() method as shown below:

```
Set myObj = CreateObject("myDll.myClass")
```

Now i want to create an object of type myClass from VBScript that is running on another machine, how can i do this. please help me how can i access that dll file, am using the `CreateObject()` function as shown below:

```
Set HD = CreateObject("myDll.myClass","myMachineName")
```

now am getting error as "permission denied".

Comment: Google "DCOM Configuration".  It's a true joy.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is supported if the assembly is built with as [COM visibility enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600012/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-net-assemblydll-from-vbscript).

[Is it possible to execute a .NET assembly(dll) from vbscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600012/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-net-assemblydll-from-vbscript)

By the way, I was pretty delighted to find out that there is a JScript compiler for .NET which allows one to write .NET code using JScript and also to target other .NET assemblies but unfortunately I haven't found anything similar for VBScript.